# How to remove underline from html link in UILabel?

Tags: html, ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

```
let attrStr = try! NSMutableAttributedString(
        data: courseList.breadcrumb.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil)
    attrStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.darkGray , range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length))
    descLbl.attributedText = attrStr
    descLbl.linkAttributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.darkGray,
        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSNumber(value: false),
        NSUnderlineColorAttributeName : UIColor.clear
    ]
```

Above is my code for Encoding HTML Tags and I have used[TTTAttributedlabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel)

```html
<a href=https://www.google.com>Subject Tutorials </a> > <a href=https://www.google.com>State Boards </a> > <a href=https://www.google.com>Madhya Pradesh State Board </a> > <a href=https://www.google.com>Hindi Medium </a> > <a href=https://www.google.com>Class 6 </a>
```

This is the HTML that I have to encode and show it without underline and have to change the color.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value for your underline attribute to the following:

```
NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone
```

Your attributes should look like:

```
descLbl.linkAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.darkGray,
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone,
    NSUnderlineColorAttributeName : UIColor.clear
]
```